# Document Set update properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, document-set

Hi i am trying to create documentset and set the properties from a webpart. I can create the document set

```
private async _CreateFolder(webUrl,listName,folderName,folderContentTypeId,folderPayload, 
itemProperties): Promise<void> {
           var ServerRelativeUrl = "/sites/mySite/myrepo" ;

            var resultData: any =  await jquery.ajax({
                                    url: webUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/myrepo" ,
                                  type: "POST",
                                  contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                                  data: JSON.stringify(folderPayload),
                                  headers: {
                                            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                                            "Slug": ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + folderName + "|" + folderContentTypeId
                                  }     
                                 });

            var result = resultData;

              const properties =  await this._updateFolderProperties(result, itemProperties);
              console.log(properties);
        }
```

I have the following for updating the properties on the document set but constantly fails with a 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403

```
 var ServerRelativeUrl = "https://mytenantRoot/sites/mySite/" ;
 var result = folder.d;
 var myDocumentSet = result.__metadata.uri;
 var listItemUri = ServerRelativeUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Myrepo')/items(" + result.Id + ")";


        var resultData: any = await jquery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: listItemUri,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        headers: {      
          "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",         
          "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
          "If-Match": "*"
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(properties),
      });
```

Properties

```
  var properties= {
'myProperty' : "Property Text"
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your request is missing the request form digest ([see this blog post](https://sympmarc.com/tag/form-digest/)). When doing any POST/PUT/DELETE with SharePoint's REST APIs, you either need to specify an authentication context (bearer access token, NTLM auth) when working remotely or a request digest + cookie (the cookie is automatically sent by the browser) when working within a SharePoint page.
Attaching the request digest would be automated for you if you were [using Pnpjs JavaScript fluent library](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/) instead of crafting the requests manually.